# SQL Server 2000 NOT EXISTS Unique Constraint Violation

Tags: sql-server, database, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure which inserts into a target table having unique constraint on two columns from a temp table.

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TBL
(id,scheme_cd,desig
)
select id,scheme_cd,desig
FROM #TEMP t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TARGET_TBL tgt 
WHERE tgt.id = t.id AND tgt.scheme_cd = t.scheme_cd)
```

temp table may contain duplicate record and TARGET_TBL has unique index on combination fo id and scheme_cd.

I am getting error as unique constraint violated.

Could someone help me in resolving the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the duplicate record?

Comment: can't remove ....ideally it should insert first record update the non key columns.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reformulating with the LEFT OUTER JOIN version of the same logical concept?

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TBL (id, scheme_cd, desig)
    SELECT t.id, t.scheme_cd, MAX(t.desig)
    FROM #TEMP t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TARGET_TBL tgt ON tgt.id = t.id AND tgt.scheme_cd = t.scheme_cd
    WHERE tgt.id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.id, t.scheme_cd
```

In this case, since the "desig" isn't unique, you can just use "max".  This assumes that if you have the same "id" and "scheme_cd", you don't really care which "desig" is inserted.  If you DO care, then your problem is that your unique primary key is insufficient and has to include "desig" as well.  Whatever process is inserting the same "id" and "scheme_cd" but with different "desig" values might be at fault too.  However, if you don't care, this change will fix the duplicate key issue you're getting.

Comment: The SELECT with a LEFT OUTER JOIN where the second table has an WHERE IS NULL clause should select all those rows in Temp that are NOT in the TARGET... and insert those.  If you execute just the SELECT clause (and have #TEMP accessible and populated) you should see just those rows in #TEMP that are not in TARGET.  And that's what you want to insert, yes?

Comment: Even that gives two rows...because no rows will be there in target table at that point ...and will try to insert into target which fails

Comment: Is there a difference between my version of code and the LEFT OUTER JOIN Version ??

Comment: Have you tried adding "DISTINCT" to the SELECT statement?

SELECT DISTINCT id, scheme_cd, desig... I've edited the answer to include the DISTINCT.

Comment: OK, I think I see your problem... the question is, when you have duplicate id/scheme_cd ... what do you want to insert for "desig"?  Does it matter?  If not, you can just add a GROUP BY and use the max "desig".  I've updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DISTINCT` in your SELECT statement

```
SELECT  DISTINCT id,scheme_cd,desig
FROM    #TEMP t
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(SELECT  1
                   FROM    TARGET_TBL tgt 
                   WHERE   tgt.id = t.id AND tgt.scheme_cd = t.scheme_cd)
```

Comment: desig may be different ...so distinct also gives duplicate records 100,ABC,MGR|100,ABC,LEAD

Comment: Then you can include `desig` also with UNIQUE... Otherwise you cannot do that. Or you can merge all Desig value and store it...